# Set HTTPS flag in a Cloud Function with in a gcloud deploy instrucction

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, gcloud-deploy

I'm trying to deploy a GCP Cloud Function

> gcloud functions deploy MyFuntion --set-env-vars
> EXPRESSPORT=0000,CODEENV=PRE --region=europe-west1 --entry-point MyPoint
> --runtime nodejs12 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --ingress-settings=all --memory=256 --timeout=30

But I can't find the flag to set the "Required HTTPS" that you can set in the Web Console:

[image]

Does anyone know the instruction?, I can't find it in de Google Cloud documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#security_levels

```sh
gcloud beta functions deploy \
--security-level=secure-always \
...
```

> **NOTE** `gcloud beta`
>
> https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy#--security-level

Comment: @DazWikin, do you know why this feature exists? Why is it possible to deploy in HTTP instead of always in https (as before)?

Comment: @guillaume-blaquiere a good question. I do not know the answer